# Concurrent dispatch queue shows as serial in Xcode 4 Debug Navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch

I'm creating a dispatch queue like

```
_dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("dispatch_queue_tag", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

also tried:

```
_dispatchQueue = dispatch_queue_create("dispatch_queue_tag", NULL);
dispatch_set_target_queue(_dispatchQueue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
```

And Xcode is showing this when I debug the app:

[image]

Is it a bug in Xcode, or is the queue being created really serial?

Comment: Your second code snippet *should* produce a serial queue. Setting its target queue to a global concurrent queue doesn't change that. So, are you sure you really tested the first approach and got that result in Xcode?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure :) I was also confused, cause I didn't know ```DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT``` was new to iOS5. How are you supposed to create a concurrent queue in iOS4? O.o I guess the only way is to GET a global, concurrent queue?

Comment: Correct, you can't create private concurrent queues until iOS5. Prior to that, the only concurrent queues are the global ones. Note that they are not interchangeable. (You can't suspend the global queues. Barrier tasks have no barrier effect on global queues. Etc.)

Comment: That sucks :P thanks for the answer though :) As for my original question, I wonder if someone can reproduce it...

Comment: I see this problem running on iOS6

Comment: I see this problem on Xcode 5, Cocoa, OS X 10.9

Answer (score 0):

I see this problem running on iOS6 but if I expand the queue it has several threads in it... I think the queue really is concurrent despite the label (if using iOS 4.3 or later). Seems like a bug.